# Verify the patch was installed

Tags: magento-1.9, patches

How can I tell if the patch **SUPEE-10570 v2** was installed on my magento store?

What are the differences between the v1 and v2 of the patch and how can I tell which version I have installed?

*Note: I am aware about the `applied.patches.list` file, however, I don't trust it 100% and would rather check the files instead.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has made a typo error, when you install V2 patch in applied.patches file it will show as V1.  As long as you have downloaded V2 and installed it, you got the latest version!!!

Comment: See, this is the thing... I am not sure. How can I confirm which version is installed? It came out some time ago and I can't remember if I have installed the v2...

Comment: Ok, easy: Open applied.patches folder, if you see the following lines  in the patch install log: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
AND app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php   ... Then you have V1 vesion. V2 Version is missing these lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link to have all details about your magento store ( included installed patches )

https://www.magereport.com/

You will get what you need.

Comment: This tool should not be trusted 100%. Also, in regards to the Security patch 10570, it gives "unknown" result. Anyway, this patch has two versions, and this is where my question comes from.

Comment: You can check this link and https://magento.com/security/patches/supee-10570  you will find the answer .

Comment: Yeah, it just say's that uninstall v1 and install v2. But my question is, how do I find out which version of the patch I have already installed... Thank you for interest and willingness to help!